# “One’s favourite”: Why “one’s”?

Tags: idioms, collocations

Brooke Candy “FMU” is my favourite song. But it’s still Brooke’s song. Why can’t I call Brooke’s song which is my favourite “Brooke’s favourite song”? It’s sort of collocation that a possessive pronoun and who likes the song should refer to the same person?

Comment: Your question says "one's" and your paragraph does not. How does that make sense?

Comment: @Lambie Have you heard the music?

Comment: This: "It’s sort of collocation that a possessive pronoun" does not mean anything.

Comment: You have to call it ***My favourite Brooke's song*** (not ***My Brooke's favourite song***), because adjectival ***favourite*** modifies the composite noun phrase ***Brooke's song***, not just ***song*** (and adjectives generally have to be placed immediately before the noun or noun *phrase* that they modify).

Comment: @FumbleFingers "My favourite Brooke's song" sounds unnatural to me. "My favourite Brooke song" is better, and "My favourite Candy song" is most natural. For a more familiar name, compare "My favourite Paul's song", "My favourite Paul song" and "My favourite McCartney" song.

Comment: @gotube: Oops! You're quite right! Dunno what I was thinking there. Well, actually, I'm pretty sure it was a combination of not paying proper attention, and only thinking of examples like *My favourite **Stones' / Beatles'** song* (showing my age, I'm afraid! :). To make matters worse though - two other users have actually *upvoted* my clearly misleading comment! But at least the fundamental point about the position / scope of ***favourite*** remains true.

Answer (score 2):

'*My* favourite' means 'the one *I* like best'. 'Brooke's favourite' would be the one *she* likes best.

You could say 'It's my favourite of all Brooke's songs'.

Comment: But any grammar books say it should be. Is it collocation?

Comment: I don't understand. Your books say it should be what?

Comment: They say possessives are possessives. They don’t say a possessive pronoun and who likes the song should refer to the same person.

Comment: @Gyiralross I suggest you not use the word collocation at this level of English learning. Read the answer again. Kate, I think this is one of those questions that ttp. :)

Comment: As I said, 'My favourite' means 'the one I like best', not that the thing I like belongs to me.

Answer (score 1):

The **'s** marker does not always indicate possession.

**My favorite song** *means* `the song that I like best.`

**Brooke's favorite song** *means* `the song that Brooke likes best.` And it means only that. It indicates nothing about the person who wrote or recorded the song, who owns the copyright, or anything like that.

**Collocation** is a reasonable way to describe this pattern.

In contrast, **Brooke's song** would usually suggest that Brooke was/is involved in the composition, performance, or ownership of the song.

Casually, you might say something like, **This is my song** when you mean, **This is my *favorite* song.** But the reverse is not true.

Another option is idiomatic, as randomhead points out, and might be what you are looking for. Without the **'s** marker, a name can function as a simple adjective. Consider:

> my favorite Stephen King novel
> my favorite Hitchcock film
> my favorite Chef John recipe
> my favorite Beatles song

All of these are quite common, and lead to these possibilities:

> my favorite Brooke Candy song
> *or*
> my favorite Brooke song

The words must come in this sequence, or the meaning will be garbled. Only one "possessive" adjective (**my**) is permitted. I mention **my favorite Beatles song** because, when spoken, you cannot hear a distinction between **Beatles** and **Beatles'.** This structure is used so frequently with musical groups whose names end in **-s** that the plural and the "possessive" are easily confused. But the "possessive" is incorrect. A native speaker instantly knows that **my favorite Hitchcock's film** is wrong.

Note: I would rather use the term "genitive" than "possessive" in this situation, but that controversy is irrelevant here.